# Roslyn load project documents failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

In a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) solution, I'm using Roslyn to load a specific project from my current solution:

```
Project myProject = 
    this.CurrentComponentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>()
        .CurrentSolution.Projects
             .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "MyProject")
```

The projct myProject is definitely loaded, but on inspection I see that:

```
myProject.HasDocuments == false
myProject.Documents is Empty
```

And yet, in Visual Studio I can see loads of documents.

If I close the solution and open the same solution but from another TFS branch, then the same code returns:

```
myProject.HasDocuments == true 
myProject.Documents is not Empty
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share a project that does this with us (in other words, a [mcve])? Otherwise, I doubt anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by:

1. Deleting the obj/debug folder
2. Cleaning
3. Transforming all T4 templates (this is ASP.NET MVC)
4. Restarting Visual Studio
5. Re-compiling

Simply re-compiling had no effect.  Can't explain why, but the above formula worked for me.

Comment: In my case, it was a matter of updating nuget packages for Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core in my analyzer